# angular js table odd column data issue

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular JS and working on table to have odd/even background colour change however I am facing some challenges.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table, td  {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
<tr> <td style="background-color:green">Name</td> <td style="background-color:green">Country</td></tr>  
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    {{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td ng-if="$even">
    {{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    {{ x.Country }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/getCustomer")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output I am getting is not desirable, the odd country data is coming blank.

Comment: You can do this in CSS:-  tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #ccc; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code, I think for the column country odd condition is missing

```
<table>
<tr> <td style="background-color:green">Name</td> <td style="background-color:green"> Country</td></tr> 
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    {{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td ng-if="$even">
    {{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    {{ x.Country }}</td>
    <td ng-if="$even">
    {{ x.Country }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with CSS much more simple and clean code.

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) td{
  //your style
}
table tr:nth-child(even) td{
}
```

You can also define the basic background color and then just use odd/even.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS for background color change.

```
<style>
table, td  {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #f1f1f1; }
</style>
```

The reason why your data is not coming properly is that you have used `ng-if="$odd"` to apply styles for odd columns.

So change your HTML to the following way and add background color from CSS.

```
  <table>
    <tr> <td style="background-color:green">Name</td> <td style="background-color:green">Country</td></tr>  
      <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
        <td>
        {{ x.Name }}</td>
        <td>
        {{ x.Name }}</td>
        <td>
        {{ x.Country }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```